# Автогенерация блоков try-catch в С#

Tags: c#, try-catch

Как обернуть в `try-catch` набор уже написанных функций?

Может быть есть какие-то средства автоматизации? Вручную мне это придётся долго делать.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Можно использовать функцию `Surround with`

1. Помечаем код с помошью комбинации клавиш: `SHIFT + CTRL + A`.
2. Нажимаем `CTRL + K, CTRL+S`
3. Вводим `T`
4. И нажимаем `Tab` или `Enter`. И код будет обернут блоком `try/catc`h.  На самом деле быстро получается, попробуйте.

Либо смотреть в сторону АОП и использовать библиотеки типа `PostSharp`.
Также видел расширение для студии, но не помню как называется.

Comment: А что должно было произойти в первом пункте? У меня эта комбинация открывает окно добавления нового элемента. Конечно ожно просто выделить код, но интересно что должно было произойти. Потомучно, заметил, комбинации клавиш на разных версиях студии могут отличаться.